# I can't figure out how to make the buttons in my WPF project revert to their original color on reset

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've created a word game as a WPF application.  The main view contains a keyboard where you click buttons to guess individual letters.  The buttons will change color based on whether your guess is correct or not.  I want the use to be able to continue playing the game when it's over, so I've created a restart button that currently resets the view model by setting the DataContext to a new view model (DataContext = new ViewModel();).  This resets everything but the color of the buttons.

`

```
 private void resetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
            Content = new View();
        }
```

`
The above code is what I've tried so far, but this only resets the content of the view.  The view model will reset if I remove the content property, but that's it.  This is my first time creating a WPF project where resetting something in this manner was necessary, so I'm not sure what to do.

Edit:
I forgot how to post how I change the color initially.  I do it in the click method for the letter buttons like so:

```
 private void LetterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedLetterButton = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
        char selectedLetter = Char.ToLower(selectedLetterButton[0]);

        if (((ViewModel)DataContext).GameLogic(selectedLetter) == true)
        {
            (sender as Button).Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Green, Colors.Green, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            (sender as Button).Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.DarkGray, Colors.DarkGray, 90);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you change the color in the first place?

Comment: And why are you using normal buttons instead `ToggleButton`? in fact you controls act as `CheckBox` but with custom visual ... also you are using ViewModel ... then this should be done via Binding (there is DataTrigger which can change style) ...

Comment: The Button Background should be bound to a property of a view model item object that holds the state of the Button. If for whatever reason you don't have such a view model, iterate over the Children collection of the common container element of the Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `DataContext` won't affect the `Background` property of the buttons that you have modified in the view.

You could for example keep track of the `Buttons` that you have modified in a `List<Button>`:

```
private readonly List<Button> _buttons = new List<Button>();

private void LetterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedLetterButton = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
    char selectedLetter = Char.ToLower(selectedLetterButton[0]);

    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (((ViewModel)DataContext).GameLogic(selectedLetter) == true)
    {
        button.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Green, Colors.Green, 90);
    }
    else
    {
        button.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.DarkGray, Colors.DarkGray, 90);
    }
    _buttons.Add(button);
}
```

...and revert to the original background colour by calling the `ClearValue` method on the buttons in this list:

```
private void resetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
    Content = new View();

    foreach (Button button in _buttons)
        button.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);
}
```